# error while sending a message from aodvRouter to adhocHost using veins_inet

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm using inet and veins_inet to simulate vanet. I wanted my nodes to use Aodv to route packets when a packet is sent from one node to another or from one node to rsu to achieve this I did the following :
I declared nodes as aodvRouters  and set their mobility to VeinsInetMobility:

```
*.node[*].typename = "AodvRouter"
*.node[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobility"
```

and rsu as AdhocHost with stationary mobility

```
*.rsu.typename = "AdhocHost"
*.rsu.mobility.typename = "StationaryMobility":
```

when I use the following code to send a message from a node[43] to node[101] or other nodes it works :

```cpp
bool nodeApp::startApplication(){
if (getParentModule()->getIndex() == 43) {
        destAddress = L3AddressResolver().addressOf(getModuleByPath("node[101]"),27);
                 auto tipChunk = makeShared<tip>();
                 timestampPayload(tipChunk);
                 tipChunk->setChunkLength(B(100));
                 tipChunk->setPacket_type("tip");
                 auto packet = createPacket("tip");
                 packet->insertAtBack(tipChunk);
                 socket.sendTo(packet.release(), destAddress, 9001);
               }
         return true;
}
```

but when I change the dest address to the rsu address it doesn't work I get the following error :

```
A runtime error occurred:

handlePacket(): Unknown protocol: id = 55, name = nexthopforwarding -- in module (inet::MessageDispatcher) Network.node[34].tn (id=3241), at t=20.000076211898s, event #1103
```

to solve this error I added the following tag

```cpp
auto req = packet->addTagIfAbsent<DispatchProtocolReq>();
req->setProtocol(&Protocol::udp); 
auto packetProtocolTag = packet->addTagIfAbsent<PacketProtocolTag>();
packetProtocolTag->setProtocol(&Protocol::udp
```

but I have the followwing error

```
A runtime error occurred:

Implicit chunk serialization is disabled to prevent unpredictable performance degradation (you may consider changing the Chunk::enableImplicitChunkSerialization flag or passing the PF_ALLOW_SERIALIZATION flag to peek) -- in module (inet::Udp) Network.node[12].udp (id=1216), at t=2.000076936898s, event #378
```

can anyone help me to send a message from a node to the rsu without broadcasting the packet